# Missing HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates--AuthRoot

Tags: windows-registry, cmd.exe

I cannot find this HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates--AuthRoot in my Registry. Please help.

Comment: What do you need to accomplish with it and what is your Windows version/edition?

Comment: I need it to check and modify for certificate revocation lists (CRL) and whether something is blocking running SQL Reporting Service. I am using Window 8.1.

Comment: Why not use Certification Authority snap-in? I have this key on Win7, but it is empty anyway.

Comment: What is the differences and where do I start it?

Comment: You should edit your question and make it about the actual problem ("I need it to check and modify for certificate revocation lists (CRL)..."), instead of your supposed solution (see [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)). As is the question itself is vague at best, and the answer(s) given no longer match the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

To view list of revoked certificates run `certmgr.msc`. Revoked certificates show under folder named `Certificate Revocation List`.

[image: Certmgr]

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730795%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you . When I run it, there seems nothing wrong with my CRL.